# how to use shared preferences in multiple fragment files

Tags: java, android, fragment, preferences, shared

I need to use shared preferences in multiple `fragment` files (cant use activity files) I have to store several string lines.

How do I initialize `shared preferences` in my fragments? How do I write / read to it?

Do I need to initialize it in my main activity or do I have to initialize it in my fragment activity files?

Tricks like:

```
Context context = getActivity();
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

... doesn't work.

Comment: What do you exactly need to do? Shared Preferences are intended to store data that you need whenever your app restarts. To share data between activities and fragments this method, although it works, is not recommended.

Comment: but i need it. maybe you could recommend a different approach? i intend to store multiple string lines

Comment: are you calling commit/apply on the instance of the editor that is putting strings into the sharedpreferences?

Comment: no, how  do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to encapsulate your SharedPreferences in some preferences class, similar to this:

```
class MyPrefs {

    private static final String FILENAME = "prefs_filename";
    private static final String KEY_SOMETHING = "something";

    private SharedPreferences mPreferences;

    public MyPrefs(Context context) {
        mPreferences = new SharedPreferences(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public void setSomething(Something value) {
       mPreferences.edit().put...(KEY_SOMETHING, value).commit();
    }

    public Something getSomething() {
       return mPreferences.getSomething(key, defaultValue);
    }
}
```

This way we provide clean API for our non-volatile data storage. `SharedPreferences` is too low-level, exposing too many details, such as storage file name and it forces us to remember all keys and value types to extract any data. It may work in simple cases, but as soon as your stored data becomes complex, it creates tons of problems. Try storing something like a user profile with few fields or a simple complex number and you'll get the idea. Using raw `SharedPreferences` will make your refactoring royal pain. Even simple data format upgrade (like schema update) will quickly become impossible with naked `SharedPreferences`.

Answer (score 0):

Using profiles should be stored in an SQL database, not shared preferences.  Hence the name.  A database stores data, preferences store preference values.  You can't complain about an API when you are misusing it.

Start with SQLite documentation